# MongoDB Aggregate - Match documents with id and give result which id not exist on collection B

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

**Collection A:**

```json
[{
    "_id": 1,
    "operation":"SEC",
    "name":"x"
},{
    "_id": 2,
    "operation": "SEC",
    "name": "y"
},
{
    "_id": 3,
    "operation": "SEC",
    "name": "z"
}]
```

**Collection B:**

```json
[{
    "user": 1,
    "operation":"SEC",
    "name":"x",
    "date": "2022-10-25"
},{
    "user": 2,
    "operation":"SEC",
    "name":"y",
    "date": "2022-10-25"
}
]
```

**Expected output:**

```json
[
{
    "_id": 3,
    "operation": "SEC",
    "name": "z"
}
]
```

I have two collections and I want to match from the first collection to the second collection by date and want to get only those that are not in the second collection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following aggregation pipeline in order to achieve your desired outpu:

```
[
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collectionB",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "user",
      "as": "collectionB"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      collectionB: {
        $size: 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      collectionB: 0
    }
  }
]
```

Please note that this is an efficient solution. You probably should add a `$match` step at the beginning in order to limit your results.

Comment: How can I lookup specific date documents from the second collections?

Comment: Well, from MongoDB 5.0 on you can specify the `pipeline` attribute in a `$lookup` stage. You can put any logic you want in there, like matching only documents from collectionB, where the date is after a specific date.

Comment: for bellow 5 or my version is 4.2?

Comment: In this case you can just use my suggestion and adjust the match step to only include documents according to your desire.

Comment: `pipeline` for `$lookup` was [added in 3.6](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.6/#more-expressive--lookup). The [change in 5.0](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/5.0/#-lookup-stage--concise-correlated-subqueries) was to allow for `pipeline` syntax to be used at the same time as `localField`/`foreignField` syntax.